# white space under an imageView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I am following [this](http://shrikar.com/ios-swift-tutorial-uipageviewcontroller-as-user-onboarding-tool/) tutorial

I have gotten the screen scrolling working I only have one problem. There is a white space under my imageView (45pixels of white space) I have no idea where this is coming from.

There was even more whitespace in the tutorial before I removed the space for the button (which doesn't seem to exist anymore... i guess it was from a previous version of the tutorial)

```
/* We are substracting 30 because we have a start again button whose height is 30*/
 self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 30)
```

It might also be a problem with my constrains so i will include them here [image: Contrains]

I will probably follow a different tutorial and get it working from scratch but I want to learn what is causing the white space in this tutorial so i am a little bit wiser

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of the 45 pixels - may have something to do with Nav bars being 44 pixels? Does your app have a Nav bar?

I can't see anything wrong with your constraints per se, but I did notice that the "incomplete constraints" indicator (yellow arrow in top right) was showing. I suspect that you may be missing some constraints.